# Logstash/Kibana JSON

Tags: elasticsearch, logstash, kibana

I am trying to ingest JSON logs using Logstash and query them using Kibana.  I have a logstash conf file that looks like this:

```
input {
  file {
    codec => "json"
    type => json
    path => "/vagrant/all-subset.json"
    start_position => beginning
  }
}
filter{
    json{
        remove_field => ["type"]
        source => "message"
        target => "tweet"
    }
}
output {
  elasticsearch {
        index => subset7
        host => localhost
        index_type => test
  }
  stdout { codec => rubydebug }
}
```

I can see that all the logs were ingested, and if I do a search on ES, I see something like this:

```
{
  "took" : 17,
  "timed_out" : false,
  "_shards" : {
    "total" : 5,
    "successful" : 5,
    "failed" : 0
  },
  "hits" : {
    "total" : 682,
    "max_score" : 1.0,
    "hits" : [ {
      "_index" : "subset7",
      "_type" : "test",
      "_id" : "syb0ETOXT3GddLY20xejBw",
      "_score" : 1.0,
      "_source":{"a": 1, "b": 2, "type": "one"}
    }, {
```

As you can see the message is in _source field.  Which is [not indexed](http://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/1.x/mapping-source-field.html) by ES.  How do I index the contents of the message?

Answer (score 0):

I don't think that your code snippet proves that the fields are not indexed. Also, your link to _source says that the _source field is not indexed; this is correct, but the elements inside it should be stored separately after they are read from _source, so they could be indexed.

Check the mappings for your index:
curl -XGET http://host:9200/[maybe_index]/_mapping

If the fields don't appear check if you have dynamic mapping setup; if not maybe consider using it?
https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/1.5/mapping-dynamic-mapping.html

Also, in Kibana 4 you may need to update the index in Settings > [your index] > Reload button

[image: reload button]

This will make newly mapped fields be fetched apparently.

A better way to determine if a field is being mapped is doing a query with an exists filter (there must be at least a document with that field holding a non-null value):

```
{
"query" : {
    "filtered": {
        "filter": {
            "exists": {
                "field": "whatever_field_name_from_json"
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
}
```